# How do I change my SQL SELECT GROUP BY query to show me which records are missing a value?

Tags: sql

I have a list of codes by area and type.  I need to get the unique codes for each type, which I can do with a simple SELECT query with a GROUP BY.  I now need to know which area does not have one of the codes.  So how do I run a query to group by unique values and tell me how records do not have one of the values?

```
ID  Area    Type    Code
1   10      A       123
2   10      A       456
3   10      B       789
4   10      B       987
5   10      C       654
6   10      C       321
7   20      A       123
8   20      B       789
9   20      B       987
10  20      C       654
11  20      C       321
12  30      A       137
13  30      A       456
14  30      B       579
15  30      B       789
16  30      B       987
17  30      C       654
18  30      C       321
```

I can run this query to group them by type and get get the unique codes:

```
SELECT tblExample.Type, tblExample.Code
FROM tblExample
GROUP BY tblExample.Type, tblExample.Code
```

This gives me this:

```
Type    Code
A       123
A       137
A       456
B       579
B       789
B       987
C       321
C       654
```

Now I need to know which areas do not have a given code.  For example, Code 123 does not appear for Area 10 and code 137 does not appear for codes 10 and 20.  How do I write a query to give me that areas are missing a code?  The format of the output doesn't matter, I just need to get the results.  I'm thinking the results could be in one column or spread out in multiple columns:

```
Type    Code    Missing Areas   or  Missing1    Missing2
A       123     30                  30  
A       137     10, 20              10          20
A       456     20                  20  
B       579     10, 20              10          20
B       789             
B       987             
C       321             
C       654
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Do you have a table  with all the types and code? So you can check what are the one missing?

Comment: A general SQL query will do; I can translate whatever you're able to offer so I didn't think I need to specify.  In this case, I'm using Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: I do not have separate tables with all the code and types.  Only the codes/types in the table are valid; i.e. there is no code D or code 111 because neither are in tblExample.1

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of the missing code/areas by first generating all combinations and then filtering out the ones that exist:

```
select t.type, c.code
from (select distinct type from tblExample) t cross join
     (select distinct code from tblExample) c left join
     tblExample e
     on t.type = e.type and c.code = e.code
where e.type is null;
```

Comment: This only work if the table already have all the types and codes. Would be better if OP has a table `Types` and `Codes`

Comment: This gives me the combined types and codes, but I need the area that's missing the code.  I need something that tells me, for example, that area 30 doesn't have a Type A with code 123.  The crucial information in that is "30".

Comment: This query has 3 major "steps": `1. It generates ALL combinations` then `2. it left joins to the existing data` and then `3. it identifies the combinations that have NOT been used` and it does this by finding where the existing data (step 2) does not join to all combinations (step 1). In short it does what you asked for.

Comment: It doesn't do the one thing that I need which is identify which area (10, 20, 30) is missing a code.  I need to figure someway to say "30 is missing code A 123" and "10 & 20 are missing A 137".  Your query only returns type and code; I need at least three columns: type, code, and area.

Comment: @boilers222 . . . Downvotes definitely do not encourage me to help anyone.  I can't speak for other people.

Comment: Just wanted to show that my question wasn't answered.  Still hoping someone has an idea how to do this.  Thanks.